# Access DOM element using Javascript only

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I have a UL in my code

```
<ul>
  <li><input type="radio" name="color" id="0" value="0"/>RED</li>
  <li><input type="radio" name="color" id="1" value="1"/>GREEN</li>
  <li><input type="radio" name="color" id="2" value="2"/>BLUE</li>
</ul>
```

IS there anyway to access these elements using the id's of these radio buttons directly or is it a compulsion to use JQUERY...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there is, of course.

Use

```
document.getElementById("ElementIdToSelect");
```

to select elements by their id's.

Answer (score 0):

```
for(var i = 0; i < 3; i++){
    var radio = document.getElementById(i + '');
    // use radio
}
```

I suggest using meaningful ids

EDIT: if you want to get selected value:

```
var radios = document.getElementsByName('color');
var selectedValue;
for(var i = 0; i < radios.length; i++){
    if(radios[i].selected){
        selectedValue = radios[i].value;
        break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You mean `document.getElementById("0")`? This should work as you required. It's javascript standard

Answer (score 0):

Yes:

```
document.getElementById('Your ID')
```

You have to remind yourself that jQuery is just plain javascript so everything made in jQuery can be made in native javascript. **Don't overuse jQuery for simple tasks**

Answer (score 0):

With the help of plain javascript you can access any selector by applying its proper ID. Jquery is the nothing but the enhanced version of Js.

**Using Javascript :-**

```
document.getElementById("0")  // wil point to first radio button

document.getElementById("1")  // wil point to second radio button
```

**Using Jquery :-**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
// Handler for .ready() called.
$('#0').YOUREVENT(function(){
  });
});
```

Ultimately they perform the same operation in the end.

Thanks...